# #1054 - Unknown column in 'on clause' whereas alias defined

Tags: mysql, sql

here's my query which gives the error "#1054 - Unknown column 'request1.orgname' in 'on clause'":

```
SELECT request.orgname, 
       request1.API_name AS 'API name', 
       SUM(CASE WHEN request.username IS NULL 
                THEN request.projects_priced_count 
                else 0 
                END) AS 'API prices calls',
       SUM(request.projects_priced_count) AS 'Total prices calls'
FROM prod_virida_pricing.request

LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT api_key.name AS 'API_name', 
           api_key.orgname AS 'Organization', 
           date(expiry_date) AS 'API expiry date', 
           is_active AS 'Active org'
    FROM prod_virida_auth.api_key
    INNER JOIN prod_virida_auth.organization ON api_key.orgname = organization.orgname
    WHERE api_key.blocked = 0 
      AND organization.is_active = 1) request1 ON request.orgname = request1.orgname

ORDER BY orgname
;
```

Comment: In your subquery you have `api_key.orgname AS 'Organization'`, so you're renaming `request1.orgname` to `request1.Organization`.

Comment: I didn't understand the problem

Comment: Once aliased source column names cease to be valid.

Comment: But the error is related to the "ON request.orgname = request1.orgname", so I can't change the word "orgname" in that line, otherwise it's not correct. I don't see where is the problem there :/

Answer (score 0):

*This will solve the problem*

Better to use aliases(table1 & table2 in the e.g.) for different subqueries to reduce confusion for SQL to understand to understand the correct columns.

```
SELECT request.orgname AS 'Organization', 
       request1.API_name AS 'API name', 
       SUM(CASE WHEN request.username IS NULL 
                THEN request.projects_priced_count 
                else 0 
                END) AS 'API prices calls',
       SUM(request.projects_priced_count) AS 'Total prices calls'
FROM prod_virida_pricing.request AS table1

LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT api_key.name AS 'API_name', 
           api_key.orgname AS 'Organization', 
           date(expiry_date) AS 'API expiry date', 
           is_active AS 'Active org'
    FROM prod_virida_auth.api_key
    INNER JOIN prod_virida_auth.organization ON api_key.orgname = organization.orgname
    WHERE api_key.blocked = 0 
      AND organization.is_active = 1) AS table2 ON table1.Organization= table2.Organization

ORDER BY table1.Organization
;
```

Comment: Thanks Abhishek, then whenever there's a LEFT OUTER JOIN it's important to use aliases? Btw I still have an error "#1054 - Unknown column 'request.orgname' in 'field list'", I think it's related to the line 1